# How to check if all of the elements in a list return true for a property using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to have a LINQ statement that calls the property IsValid.
If all elements returned true, I want the statement to return true as well.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var allValid = myList.All(item => item.IsValid);
```

Answer (score 7):

You might want to safe guard or be specific. Enumerable.All returns true if the collection is empty

```
var allValid = myList.Any() && myList.All(item => item.IsValid);
```

See here [Why does Enumerable.All return true for an empty sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884888/why-does-enumerable-all-return-true-for-an-empty-sequence)

Answer (score 6):

You need the [Enumerable.All<TSource> method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
bool everythingsZen = anEnumerable.All(a => a.IsValid);
```

Comment: IsValid is a "property", in the OP's question.  This would mean "a => a.IsValid" (no method here).