# why this condition returns true?

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Enumerable.All return true for an empty sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884888/why-does-enumerable-all-return-true-for-an-empty-sequence)

Code:

```
var line = "name:";
Console.Write(line.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1].All(char.IsDigit));
```

How it is possible? it should not return false? after`:` is an empty string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

> true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the
>   specified predicate, **or if the sequence is empty**; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 8):

It's a [vacuously true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) expression.

All of the characters are digits because you can't find a counter-example. This code:

```
return s.All(char.IsDigit);
```

is roughly equivalent to this loop:

```
foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(c)) { return false; }
}
return true;
```

In this rewritten version it should be clear that if there are no characters in the string then the loop body will never be entered and so the result is true.

Comment: Upvote for good Wikipedia link, never knew that had a name :)

Answer (score 6):

This is because of two reasons:

1. As mentioned in your *phantom edit update*, your indexing condition grabs the *second* entry in the array returned by `Split` (C# counts starting at 0)

   ```
   var parts = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
   // parts[0] == "name";
   // parts[1] == "";
   ```
2. [`Enumerable.All<TSource>(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) returns `true` if the input sequence is empty

   > Return Value
   >
   > Type: System.Boolean
   >   true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or if the sequence is empty; otherwise, false.