# Linq All on empty collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I need to check if all definitions contains some specific data. It works fine except the case when GroupBy returns empty collection.

```
var exist = dbContext.Definitions
                     .Where(x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) && x.CountryId == countryId)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId)
                     .All(...some condition...);
```

How to rewrite this so All would return false on empty collection?

UPDATE:
It is a LINQ to SQL and I wanted to execute this in single call.

UPDATE2: 
I think this works:

```
var exist = dbContext.Definitions
                     .Where(x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) && x.CountryId == countryId)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId)
                     .Count(x => x
                        .All(...some condition...)) == propertyTypeIds.Count;
```

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects or something else? The answers could be radically different.

Comment: Try using AllOrDefault

Comment: `All` won't return false on an empty collection. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884888/why-does-enumerable-all-return-true-for-an-empty-sequence

Comment: @sr28 OP is asking the opposite of that.

Comment: @elloco999: Um, which method is that? Can you link to MSDN?

Comment: @JonSkeet I stand corrected. I was sure an AllOrDefault function existed but it seems it doesn't. My apologies.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using LINQ to Objects, I'd just write my own extension method. My [Edulinq project](https://github.com/jskeet/edulinq) has sample code for [`All`](https://github.com/jskeet/edulinq/blob/master/src/Edulinq/All.cs), and adapting that is pretty simple:

```
public static bool AnyAndAll<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    }

    bool any = false;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        any = true;
        if (!predicate(item))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return any;
}
```

This avoids evaluating the input more than once.

Comment: I was about to write the same code just now but I would have probably kept a counter internally instead of a bool for added value. Not sure if I'd return it straight (as in `int AllAndCount(...)`) or in addition to the bool using an out parameter (as in ``bool AnyAndAll(..., out int count)`).

Comment: Also, kindly note that you can avoid the cost of setting `any = true` over and over again by using the following code at the expense of a certain amount of readability: `using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
{ if (enumerator.MoveNext()) { do { if (!predicate(enumerator.Current)) { return false; } } while (enumerator.MoveNext()); return true; } return false; }`

Answer (score 6):

You could make use of `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method, and adjust your `some condition` so that it evaluates `null` to `false`.

```
var exist = definitions
    .Where(x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) && x.CountryId == countryId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .All(...some condition...));
```

Comment: Very Clever! In other words, `.All(g => g != null && ( ...some condition... ))`. Extra parenthesis may not be required depending on how `...some condition...` is written.

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to do this using an `Aggregate`, along the lines of:

```
.Aggregate(new {exists = 0, matches = 0}, (a, g) =>
        new {exists = a.exists + 1, matches = a.matches + g > 10 ? 1 : 0})
```

(Here, `g > 10` is my test)

And then simple logic that `exists` is greater than zero and that `exists` and `matches` have the same value.

This avoids running the whole query twice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do it in two steps :

```
var definitions = definitions.Where(
                    x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) && x.CountryId == countryId)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId);

var exist = definitions.Any() && definitions.All(...some condition...);
```

Comment: There's no need for the nullity check - but you need to be aware that this will execute the query twice.

Comment: If this is something like Entity Framework though, it will cause 2 queries to be run against the database.

Comment: True, it'll execute the query twice. Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: first answer wouldn't have worked.

If you rearrange your query somewhat, you can use `DefaultIfEmpty` without needing to change your condition:

```
var exist = dbContext.Definitions
                     .Where(x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) 
                                  && x.CountryId == countryId)
                     .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId);

           // apply the condition to all entries, 
           // resulting in sequence of bools (or empty), 
           // to permit the next step
                     .Select(...some condition...) 

           //if seq is empty, add `false`
                     .DefaultIfEmpty(false)

           //All with identity function to apply the query and calculate result
                     .All(b => b)
         );
```

Comment: To steal a comment form a deleted answer (that you can't see): "But then you need to negate the result from Any to get the same results as were being obtained from All (true if it's true for all, false otherwise) and you're right back at the same situation"

Comment: @DavidG is the new version better?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another trick:

```
var exist = dbContext.Definitions
    .Where(x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) && x.CountryId == countryId)
    .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId)
    .Min(some_condition ? (int?)1 : 0) == 1;
```

It utilizes the fact that the above `Min<int?>` method returns:

> (A) `null` when the set is empty
>   (B) `0` if the condition is not satisfied for some element
>   (C) `1` if the condition is satisfied for all elements

so we simple check the result for (C) using the nullable value comparison rules.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing your own extension method? (I am pretty sure you will name it better)

```
public static bool NotEmptyAll<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
    Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return collection != null
        && collection.Any()
        && collection.All(predicate);
}
```

Then call it instead of `All`

```
var exist = definitions.Where(
        x => propertyTypeIds.Contains(x.PropertyTypeId) && x.CountryId == countryId)
         .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyTypeId)
         .NotEmptyAll(
             ...some condition...));
```

Comment: Note that this executes the query twice, which may well be a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for warning @JonSkeet. But it the only solution which comes into MY mind. As it is not tagged `EntityFramework`, I think GENERALLY it should not cost much.

Comment: Well it'll cost twice as much as doing it once... it's also quite unLINQ-like... there's no regular LINQ operator which evaluates its input more than once, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the alternative to `All` that returns `false` if collection is empty:

```
var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 0); //empty collection

collection
  .Select(IsValid)
  .DefaultIfEmpty(false)
  .All(b => b);
```

Or as an extension method:

```
public static bool AnyAndAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate) =>
  collection
    .Select(predicate)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(false)
    .All(b => b);
```