# Linq - Checking for all but only if there is at least one

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a query in Linq which needs to check if **one or more** items in a list pass predicate `A()`, and **none** pass predicate `B()`. It needs to be a single query to enable Linq to SQL. So for the following lists the results should be as follows where `a` passes predicate `A()` and `b` passes predicate `B()`:

```
1. [ a, a ] => true
2. [ a ]    => true
3. [ a, b ] => false
4. [ b, b ] => false
5. [ b ]    => false
6. [ ]      => false
```

I've tried the following, but each have certain situations where they fail:

```
// Fails in case 6
MyList.All(x => A(x) && !B(x));

// Fails in case 3
MyList.Where(x => !B(x)).Count(x => A(x)) > 0;

// This works, but it's not a single query anymore
MyList.All(x => A(x) && !B(x)) && Mylist.Count() > 0;
```

I feel like what I need here is something equivalent to all, but which returns false for an empty list. For example this would pass in all cases:

```
MyList.AllButReturnFalseIfListIsEmpty(x => A(x) && !B(x));
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you something similar to my answer to [Linq All on empty collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039287/linq-all-on-empty-collection/39044389#39044389):

```
var result = MyList.Max(x => B(x) ? (int?)2 : A(X) ? (int?)1 : (int?)0) == 1;
```

It utilizes how `Max<int?>` method works

(A) If the sequence is empty, it returns `null`
(B) If there is at least one element matching B, the result is `2`
(C) If there is at least one element not matching B and matching A, the result is `1`
(D) Otherwise the result is `0`

So we simple check for case (C).

Comment: Clever! Full marks for being terse, although I'm not sure this is as easy to follow as the accepted answer. Both are fairly out there, though.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity (since I've also learned something today from @dasblinkenlight), does `Aggregate` query get translated to SQL (I'm pretty sure `Max` does)?

Comment: Nevermind. As I suspected, EF does not support `Aggregate`.

Comment: Okay, just tested this and you're right. Switching this to my accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = MyList
    .Select(x => B(x) ? -1 : (A(x) ? 1 : 0))
    .Aggregate(0, (p, v) => v == -1 || p == -1 ? -1 : p + v) > 0;
```

The query works as follows:

- `Select` produces `-1` when `B` is `true`; otherwise, it produces `1` if `A` is `true` and `0` when `A` is false
- `Aggregate` checks this list of numbers from `-1, 0, 1`. If it sees `-1`, the result of the aggregation is `-1`. Otherwise, the result of the aggregation is sum of positive values.
- Comparison at the end makes sure there's at least one `A` and no `B`s.

Comment: "*It needs to be a single query to enable Linq to SQL*"

Comment: @IvanStoev It *is* a single query.

Comment: I'm going to try this once I get my head around it - looks promising!

Comment: Well, technically it is, but in reality it's a select query that returns calculated value per each record, and aggregation occurs at client side (`Aggregate` is basically `foreach` - there is no `Queryable.Aggregate`). I was thinking for something similar, but translatable to SQL.

Comment: @IvanStoev [Are you sure there is no `Queryable.Aggregate`?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Apparently I'm not :) May be I'm too much in EF and what is/is not supported there. Still I doubt that will be translated to SQL though.

Comment: I've changed my accepted answer to Ivan's, as he's correct that this isn't translated to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyList.All(x => MyList.Any() && A(x) && !B(x));
```

Comment: This is part of a Linq to SQL query within EntityFramework, so I don't have access to the list as a variable. It's all a single expression, e.g. - `dbContext.MyTable.Any(x => x.thing == true);`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if there's any item after the evaluation?

```
MyList.Where(x => A(x) && !B(x)).Any();
```

Comment: This returns true if the list contains some values which pass predicate `B()`

Comment: @AlfieWoodland oops, meant Where.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use All() if you want it to return false for empty collection. Take a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the
>   specified predicate, or **if the sequence is empty**; otherwise, false.

Instead, I would try something like this:

```
MyList.Where(x => A(x) && !B(x)).Any();
```

Comment: This will return true for lists containing values which pass predicate `B()`.